# Knowledge and articles in naplili template community

Tags: knowledge, community, articles

we are facing below few problems using napili template for community.

Knowledge is enabled ,yet we are not able to see "article type" object/setting anywhere in the system for system admin.
We created knowledge articles and assigned to all partners and did all appropriate access settings and all yet we are not able to see those articles in naplili. 3.we are not able to see articles in trending articles by topics component.
we are struggling with this for couple of days.

Hope you guys help me in figuring this out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your users need the 'Knowledge User' feature license enabled in order to access this.

Go to their profiles and make sure that the 'Knowledge User' box is checked for everyone who needs access. Even admins need this in order to see/access Knowledge settings and objects (including article types).